# How to categorize in django admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I have register my models in `admin.py` as

```
admin.site.register(Food_Gallery)
admin.site.register(Gym)
admin.site.register(Gym_Gallery)
admin.site.register(Gym_Pricing_Plans)
admin.site.register(Gym_Programs)
admin.site.register(Trainer)
admin.site.register(Farm)
admin.site.register(Farm_Gallery)
admin.site.register(Farm_Products)
```

This shows all the models in a single page in django admin

I want to categorize these models into certain categories and display their respective models.How to manage this?

Certain examples as

```
Food
Gym
Farm
```

Comment: I think this answer should give appropriate answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46340047/7839727

Answer (score 4):

Simply please create a separate App for separate model categories.

You can create app like this (`settings.py`):

```py
python manage.py startapp food
python manage.py startapp gym
python manage.py startapp farm

INSTALLED_APP += [
   'farm',
   'food',
   'gym',
]
```

And in `admin.py`:

```py
admin.site.register(food)
admin.site.register(gym)
admin.site.register(farm)
```

This is right way.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

**1. Customize the Django admin site.**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial07/#customize-the-admin-index-page

**2. Create different apps for each categories.**

In terminal,

```
python manage.py startapp food
python manage.py startapp gym
python manage.py startapp farm
```

In food/admin.py file,

```
admin.site.register(Food_Gallery)
```

In gym/admin.py file,

```
admin.site.register(Gym)
admin.site.register(Gym_Gallery)
admin.site.register(Gym_Pricing_Plans)
admin.site.register(Gym_Programs)
admin.site.register(Trainer)
```

In farm/admin.py file,

```
admin.site.register(Farm)
admin.site.register(Farm_Gallery)
admin.site.register(Farm_Products)
```

You also have to add your apps in `settings.py` file and maybe you need to modify some of your code.

Each method has its pros and cons, so it is up to you which to use.